# Recycling maths expressions from previous lines

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing

It just occurred to me that I spend a large amount of time when typing TeX documents copying and pasting expressions from previous lines of working out. If I make a mistake in that expression, I then have to go down through all the following lines and update it.

Is there a way to assign a math expression to some kind of symbol so that instead of having to repeat myself, I can simply import that expression into math-mode environments further down the page. Once the document was rendered, this would appear identical to just copying and pasting the TeX code for the expression from one line to the next.

This would be super useful whenever I have a common sub-expression that I have to repeat over and over again. If I made a mistake, I could simply modify the original version of the math expression, and it would update all the following equations.

Comment: You can either use a clipboard manager (such as  `Ditto`)  or try defining a macro in your preamble.

Comment: Ditto won't work for me since it's Windows only. Furthermore, it doesn't really do what I asked about in the question. Macros in the preamble sound nicer - but I feel like having some of my equations at the top of the document would be annoying.

Comment: `\newcommand` instructions -- and related instructions such as `\newlength`,  `\newcounter`, and `\renewcommand` -- aren't limited to occurring in the preamble. They can occur (almost) anywhere.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX StackExchange! If you are a Mac user, then check out LaTeXiT, which is free, very well maintained, and allows you to create catalogs of equations whose code can be copied and pasted into your documents. It's Mac only though. It's also provided with MacTeX and also available from https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-features.php.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I use Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked,

> Is there a way to assign a math expression to some kind of symbol so that instead of having to repeat myself, I can simply import that expression into math-mode environments further down the page?

Your posting makes it sound like you could benefit significantly from acquiring a working knowledge of how to go about creating and using LaTeX macros. These macros may be defined, and re-defined, almost anywhere in a LaTeX document. (Well, I suppose there's no point in defining them after `\end{document}`, right?) Creating macros via `\newcommand` is not limited to the document's preamble -- although there are usually very good reasons for preferring to place macro definitions in the preamble...

*Addendum*: As @egreg has pointed out in a comment, a -- likely unexpected and highly undesirable -- side-effect of having `\newcommand` instructions after `\begin{document}` is that one has to be careful not to insert space characters inadvertently, as these can affect TeX's spacing and even line-breaking routines. To keep TeX from inserting a space at the end of the `\newcommand` instruction, be sure to terminate it with a `%` (comment) character.

I will let you guess what the following test document produces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World.
\newcommand\CommonTerm{a^2+b^2}% <-- note the comment character
\[
\CommonTerm \quad \sqrt{\CommonTerm} \quad -\ln(\CommonTerm)
\]
\end{document}
```

Aside, for the sake of completeness: There are, in fact, a handful of math-related definitional activities which *must* occur in the preamble. E.g., if you wish to use `\DeclareMathOperator` (provided by the `amsmath` package), you *must* do so in the preamble.

Comment: Beware of spaces! There are two of them before `\[` in your code and the implicit `\par` that starts display math mode just removes one of them. Depending on the length of the previous line, you might end up with a spurious empty line.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for pointing out the potential whitespace issues that may be caused by placing `\newcommand` (and similar) instructions in the body of the document. I've posted an addendum to point this out.